# tab navigation in react native is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,  TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";

const Header = props => {
    const {
        navigationState,
        navigation,
        activeTintColor,
        inactiveTintColor
    } = props;
    const activeTabIndex = navigation.state.index;
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerHeader}>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textWhite}>Win Bets</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textWhiteSmall}>win cash daily</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          {navigationState.routes.map((route, index) =>{
              const isRouteActive = index === activeTabIndex;
              const tintColor = isRouteActive ? activeTintColor : inactiveTintColor;
              return (
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
                  key={route.routeName}
                  >
                      <View>
                          <Text
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 17,
                                textTransform: "capitalize",
                                color: `${tintColor}`,
                                fontWeight: `${isRouteActive ? "700" : "normal"}`
                            }}
                            >
                                {route.routeName}
                            </Text>
                      </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              );
          })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

the tabs show as they are supposed to be, but they are not clickable and cant navigate to a different page... also the home page doesnt show.
what could be the problems, or how do i configure the routes and routeName?